# If $ \sum_{n\geq 1}\mu( \{|f_n|\geq n\})<\infty $ then $ f_n-f_n 1_{|f_n|\leq n}\underset {n}{\to} 0 $

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal {A},\mu) $ be a finite measure space and $\{f_n\} $ be sequence of bounded function in $L^1$ such that
$$
\sum_{n\geq 1}\mu( \{|f_n|\geq n\})<\infty
$$

Can we say that
$$
f_n-f_n 1_{|f_n|\leq n}\underset {n}{\to} 0
$$

I thought of Borel Cantelli's lemma but I am unable to use it.

Comment: So by borel cantelli you get $\mu ( \limsup \{|f_n| \ge n\}) = 0$, so $\mu( \liminf \{|f_n| \le n\})= 1$, which means, we have a set $E_0$ of full measure, such that for $x \in E_0$ we get $N(x) \in \mathbb N$ such that for $n> N(x)$ it holds that $f_n(x) \le n$, so for $n > N(x)$ we get $f_n(x) - f_n1_{\{|f_n|\le n\}} = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is consequence of the direct art of the Barel-Cantelli theorem. In terms of our problem, the function $g(x)=\sum_n\mathbb{1}_{\{|f_n|\geq n\}}$ is integrable asn so is finite $\mu$-a.s.
That means that for a.s. $x\in E$, there is $N(\omega)$ such that $n\geq N(\omega)$ implies $\mathbb{1}_{\{|f_n|\geq n\}}=0$. That is, for $n\geq N(\omega)$,
$$
f_n(\omega)-f_n\mathbb{1}_{\{|f_n|\geq n\}}(\omega)=f_n(\omega)\mathbb{1}_{\{|f_n|\geq n\}}(\omega)=0
$$